# Toggling buttons within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code is used to toggle buttons within a `div`:

```js
var chosen = {};
var form_name = 'the_div';
function(what) {
   if('number' != typeof what) { // toggle-one
        var el = $(what);
        var name = el.html();
        var ch = ['success','default'];
        if( !chosen[name] ) ch.unshift(ch.pop());
        el.removeClass('btn-' + ch[0]).addClass('btn-' + ch[1]);
        chosen[name] = !chosen[name];
        return;
    }
    var choices = $('#'+form_name).find('div');
    switch(what) { // when toolbar button clicked
        case 1: // select-all
            choices.each(function(idx,el){
                var el = $(el);
                var name = el.html();
                if(!chosen[name]) {
                    el.removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-success');
                    chosen[name] = true;
                }
            });
            break;
        case 0: // select-none
            choices.each(function(idx,el){
                var el = $(el);
                var name = el.html();
                if(chosen[name]) {
                    el.removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-default');
                    chosen[name] = false;
                }
            });
            break;
        case -1: // select-inverse / toggle-all
            choices.each(function(idx,el){
                var el = $(el);
                var name = el.html();
                var ch = ['success','default'];
                if(!chosen[name]) ch.unshift(ch.pop());
                el.removeClass('btn-'+ch[0]).addClass('btn-'+ch[1]);
                chosen[name] = !chosen[name];
            });
            break;
    }
}
```

Any suggestion on how to simplify this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some of my suggestions:

- Declare `static` things at the top. i.e. `var ch = ['success','default'];` it is declared twice.
- Duplicate code should be pulled into functions (see below).
- Be consistent: `el.removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-success');` and `el.removeClass('btn-'+ch[1]).addClass('btn-'+ch[0]);` Either make use of `ch` or get rid of it (I suggest the first).

Duplicate code:

```
var el = $(el);
var name = el.html();
var ch = ['success','default'];
if(!chosen[name]) ch.unshift(ch.pop());
el.removeClass('btn-'+ch[0]).addClass('btn-'+ch[1]);
chosen[name] = !chosen[name];
```

Something like:

```
var ch = ['success','default'], 
    toggleElement = function (el) {
        var el = $(el),
            name = el.html();

        if(!chosen[name]) ch.unshift(ch.pop());
        el.removeClass('btn-'+ch[0]).addClass('btn-'+ch[1]);
        chosen[name] = !chosen[name];
    };
```

Your `case 0` and `case 1` statements could be made into a function as well as they're identical (other than the `true/false`).